# How to make dynamic edm model support odata queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have been trying to adapt the DynamicEdmModelCreation sample from https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/DynamicEdmModelCreation into a workable v3 version (I want to load odata directly into excel, which doesn't support odata v4 yet)

I added `config.AddODataQueryFilter()` to the setup and `[EnableQuery]` on the Controller's get method, but I now receive the exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in System.Web.Http.OData.dll
>
> Additional information: 'EnumerableQuery`1' cannot be serialized using the ODataMediaTypeFormatter.

Which is being thrown from https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.Http.OData/OData/Formatter/ODataMediaTypeFormatter.cs#L577

Is the fact that my Controller's Get method is returning an `EdmEntityObjectCollection` an issue? I would have thought that just adding the EnableQuery attribute would be enough for the framework to know how to apply that query operation to the `EdmEntityObjectCollection` that I'm returning (which will have lots more data than potentially needed)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but did you ever get a solution to this? Looks like it might still be an open issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have done is right, but OData WebApi doesn't support query options in un-typed scenario now, and there is an open [issue](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/165) about this feature.